# Character class (square brackets) ignored while matching regex

Tags: regular-expression

Why `[]([a].*)` matches `[](b)`? I would expect it to require `a` to be the first character in `()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because Vim is actually seeing all the characters in between the very first `[` and the last `]` as a *single*
character class that will match any one of `]`, `(`, `[`, or `a`.

In other words, what Vim is seeing here is `[]([a].*)`, with the bold part being the character class. So it's matching any of these four characters, followed by everything until a `)`.

This happens because, in order to match a literal `]` in a character class, it needs to be the first character listed in the character class. So if you only have a `[]` an no other character class in the regexp (for example `[](.*)`), Vim will find that to be an invalid character class and match those characters literally. But as soon as you add another `]` somewhere later in that regexp, you're now making it valid and making it match any character in between.

You can easily fix it by adding a backslash before the first `[`, to force it to match a literal bracket: `\[]([a].*)`.